# VK API на Python сервере чат бот

Tags: python-3.x, vkontakte-api, сервер, бот

Пытаюсь сделать мини бота по этому уроку https://proglib.io/p/python-vk-api-3/
Но на сервере выдает это
[image: ошибка]

вот код

```
# A very simple Flask Hello World app for you to get started with...

import vk
from time import sleep
from lxml import html
import requests as req
from flask import Flask

login = '89326949892'
password = '12345qwerty'
vk_id = '3570608'  #ID_ВАШЕГО_ПРИЛОЖЕНИЯ
session = vk.AuthSession(app_id=vk_id, user_login=login, user_password=password)

vkapi = vk.API(session)

messages = vkapi.messages.get(count=1)
last = messages['items'][0]['id']


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
return 'Привет!'

def bash(id, mode='u'):
try:
    r = req.get('http://bash.im/random')
    doc = html.document_fromstring(r.text)
    bash = '\n'.join(doc.xpath('//*[@id="body"]/div[3]/div[@class="text"]/text()'))
    if mode == 'c':
        vkapi.messages.send(chat_id=id, message=bash)
    else:
       vkapi.messages.send(user_id=id, message=bash)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    if "~bash~" in message['body']:
        if 'chat_id' in message:
            bash(message['chat_id'], 'c')
        else:
            bash(message['user_id'])

def print_help(id, mode='u'):
try:
    message = """=== VK-бот ===
    Доступные команды:
    &#_9989; ~bash~ -- случайная цитата с bash.im
    &#_9989; ~help~ -- показать помощь"""
    if mode == 'c':
        vkapi.messages.send(chat_id=id, message=message)
    else:
       vkapi.messages.send(user_id=id, message=message)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    if "~help~" in message['body']:
        if 'chat_id' in message:
            print_help(message['chat_id'], 'c')
        else:
            print_help(message['user_id'])


while True:
try:
    messages = vkapi.messages.get(last_message_id=last)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    sleep(4)
    continue
if not messages['items']: # Если нет новых сообщений
    sleep(4)
    continue
last = messages['items'][0]['id']
for message in messages['items']:
    # временные заглушки
    if "~bash~" in message['body']:
        bash(message['user_id'])
sleep(4)
```

Comment: Тебе предлагают посмотреть логи (*.error.log) там наверняка ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Почему то мне кажется что у тебя проблема с табуляцией. К тому же vk старый модуль, куда лучше использовать vk_api (имхо он обновляется, удобнее и у него больше функций). И если вдруг тебе будет недостаточно *.error.log, запусти свой скрипт в консоли которая там есть, и посмотри ошибку.

Да и что касается твоего проекта в целом, вк не очень любит страницы-боты, но относится лояльно к группам-ботам. Если есть возможность сделай его под группу с использованием CallBack API. Или под страницу, но с LongPoll и запускай у себя на машине. На pythonanywhere дают очень мало процессорного времени для этого.